# Como fazer update com contagem em SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tenho a seguinte tabela:

```
Nome   | Posicao
Item1  | NULL 
Item2  | NULL
Item3  | NULL
```

Gostaria que ela ficasse da seguinte forma:

```
Nome   | Posicao
Item1  | 1 
Item2  | 2
Item3  | 3
```

O critério de Ordenação é Nome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Digamos que você possui a seguinte tabela:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Pessoa](
[nome] [varchar](50) NULL,
[posicao] [int] NULL
)
```

Para isso, utilizaremos este `insert` como base:

```
insert into pessoa values 
('Mariana', 1),
('Joao', 2),
('Maria', 3),
('Paula', 4),
('Marcos', 5),
('Ana', 6),
('Pedro', 7)
```

Para realizar o `update`, basta utilizar a função [ROW_NUMBER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms186734(v=SQL.120).aspx) para ordenar sua tabela de acordo com o campo desejado, ficando assim o `update`:

```
UPDATE Pessoa 
SET Posicao = new_posicao
FROM (SELECT Posicao, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Nome) 
                      AS new_posicao FROM Pessoa)
Pessoa
```

Answer (score 4):

Acho que é isto que precisa (não tenho como testar):

```
DECLARE @contador int;
SET @contador = 1;
UPDATE tabela SET @contador = Posicao = @contador + 1 ORDER BY Nome;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Update/Increment.sql).

Comment: Interessante, mas só funciona sem o `ORDER BY` e com `@contador = 0` no começo. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d866c/1

Answer (score 3):

Você pode utilizar a função [ROW_NUMBER()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms186734(v=SQL.120).aspx) para fazer essa contagem. Segue exemplo de query abaixo.

```
WITH ALGUMNOME AS (
                   SELECT 
                           NOME AS 'NOME',
                           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NOME DESC) RN
                   FROM 
                           TABELA
                   ORDER BY
                           NOME
                   )

UPDATE TABELA SET POSICAO = RN FROM TABELA
INNER JOIN ALGUMNOME ON ALGUMNOME.NOME = TABELA.NOME
```